# Nvidia prime not working with 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I tried using the 361 and 364 drivers, I get the following error when I run nvidia-settings:

```
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
   have been installed along with this driver at either
   /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-367.18-key-documentation
   or /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
   application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
   preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
   Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```